# Laravel with TwigBridge method_field not working

Tags: php, twig, laravel-5

I'm following the basic quickstart with laravel 5. I'm deviating only in that I'm using TwigBridge to allow me to use twig templates instead of blade. I'm getting in error when I tried to load my view.

```
Unknown "method_field" function in "/home/vagrant/laravel-test/resources/views/tasks.twig" at line 63.
```

method_field should be an available default helper function in laravel. I'm not really sure why twigbridge isn't finding it. Is there something I'm missing I need to make this function available to TwigBridge?

Edit

Here's my code:

```
{% if tasks|length > 0 %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Current Tasks
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped task-table">

                <!-- Table Headings -->
                <thead>
                    <th>Task</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </thead>

                <!-- Table Body -->
                <tbody>
                    {% for task in tasks %}
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Task Name -->
                            <td class="table-text">
                                <div>{{ task.name }}</div>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <form action="{{ url('task/'~task.id) }}" method="POST">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

                                    <button>Delete Task</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

---

Edit 2

I partially figured it out. I had to add `method_field` to the `config/twigbridge.php` file in the `functions` array:

```
'functions' => [
    'elixir',
    'head',
    'last',
    'method_field',
].
```

This got it to run the function, however the output is converted to html entities because it actually renders the input tag text instead of the tag itself. So I need to figure out away to make it not escape the output.

Comment: If you're not using 5.1+, then I don't think that method is available to you. You'll need to set the field manually: `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">`

Comment: I think the package has not provided for the method in question. If that is the case, opening an issue on the TwigBridge GH repo would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you have to add the function to the config/twigbridge.php with an `is_safe` option. That can be done this way:

in `/app/config/twigbridge.php`

```
'functions' => [
    // Other functions
    'method_field' => [
        'is_safe' => [true],
    ],
],
```